# Untrusted Certificate Not just on my computer?

Tags: firefox

yesterday I tried going to several websites but an "untrusted certificate" warning popped up several times.  Eventually it went away.  I am the latest version of Mozilla Firefox.  I also connect to the wifi through my phone which has a Chrome browser.  It too popped up with a very similar message.  Any reason why this would happen?  Also it was after daylight savings so could that have anything to do with it?  Yes my phone and computer both displayed the correct time/date.  Thanks.

Comment: If it happened on multiple independent sites it's possible that you were the victim of a man-in-the-middle attack.  It wouldn't be a bad idea to change your passwords on any sites you visited while on the wifi network yesterday.

Comment: Thanks and will do.  How can I detect if I was hacked?  And if it doesn't pop up anymore does that mean I am not being hacked anymore?

Comment: If you didn't click any "Ignore and proceed" or "Add exception" buttons, it's possible that no information was compromised.  Even so, you should assume that you were hacked unless there's good reason to believe otherwise.  For your second question, as long as you didn't add any exceptions or bypass the warnings, you should be safe if the warning doesn't pop up anymore.

Comment: Sounds good.  Now if my phone is connected to the wifi and the apps on my phone were opened is it possible they would have access to that information?

Comment: That's harder to say, as it's up to the app developers to decide whether their apps verify the legitimacy of SSL certificates before sending sensitive data, though apps from major companies probably do.  Android developers can connect to an SSLSocket when they need their apps to send information securely, but it provides the option of bypassing all certificate checks. Considering this it wouldn't hurt to change the passwords of all services connected to a phone app as well.